# How can I set an attribute without a value to an html tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I am trying to use vanilla-tilt.js and the easiest way is to add data-tilt to your tag:

```
<div class="your-element" data-tilt></div>
```

However, the platform I have to use it at right now doesn't allow me to access the html source code.

I can only access **css** and **js** code editors. So, my only option is through javascript.

So, how do I add the 'data-tilt' attribute to the div with the `.your-element` class if I use **jquery**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need access to HTML.
[Read the DOCS.](https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/)

So by having in HTML:

```
<div class="your-element"></div>
```

all you need is:

```
VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelector(".your-element"), {
    max: 25,
    speed: 400
});
```

---

For multiple elements I suppose this should do the job:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".your-element")].forEach( el =>
    VanillaTilt.init(el, {max: 25, speed: 400})
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like charm, but... I have several elements with the same class and the jquery seems to work only on the first one. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .attr with an empty string:

`$('#your-elem-id').attr('data-tilt', '');`

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can use the .attr() method to add an atribute. attr() need 2 parameters the first one is the attribute name and de second the value other way is using javascript using the setAttribute method that works equal to attr() method.

**Jquery:**

```js
$(".your-element").attr("data-tilt", "SOMEVALUE");

console.log($(".your-element"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="your-element"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("your-element");
element[0].setAttribute("data-tilt", "SOMEVALUE");
console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="your-element" data-tilt></div>
```

In the end if you inspect the element you will to see the new attribute attached in the DOM.